# Check a 2D associated array for a string, return the information (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am learning PHP and I am looking to search an array for a given string and return some values if it matches. I have tried using `in_array()` and `array_search` but both haven't been able to match/return the value correctly.

**print_r($names);**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => A
            [age] => 42
            [location] => Australia
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => B
            [age] => 21
            [location] => France
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Z
            [age] => 50
            [location] => Japan
        )
)
```

I would like to check to see if a name exists in the array and return the information for the same index location.

```
$name="A";
if (in_array($name, $names)) {
    $age=$names['age'];
    $location=$names['location'];
    echo "$name was found! Their Age is: $age, They are based in: $location";
}
else{
    echo"$name was not found";
}
```

However, the name is not found and the age and location data is not loaded.

**Output:**

```
A was not found
```

**Expected Output:**

```
A was found! Their Age is: 42, They are based in: Australia
```

*Testing using array_search()*

```
$result = array_search("$name",$names);
echo $result;
```

No value printed.

Any feedback on how I can fix my `(in_array)` or how I would go about using `array_search()` to list the information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$position = array_search($name, array_column($your_array, 'name'));
$info = $your_array[$position];
```

**Explanation**

```
array_column($your_array, 'name')
```

Will return the array with all names with respective indexes.

```
array_search($name, array_column($your_array, 'name'))
```

Will return the index where the name is found.

```
$info = $your_array[$position]
```

Will store the particular sub-array in `$info`.

So it should be something like-

```
echo $info['name'] . " was found! Their Age is: " . $info['age'] . ", They are based in: " . $info['location'];
```

[array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) & [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

[Working code](https://eval.in/736512)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Sougata Bose for your quick reply and for explaining how each step was working, it was very helpful for a beginner like me :)

Comment: is it also possible to continue searching for another instance of the same name?

If the search $name = 'Z' and there exists two instances of Z, can you display the information for both instances?

    '2' => array
        (
            'name' => 'Z',
            'age' => 50,
            'location' => 'Japan',
        ),

    '999' => array
        (
            'name' => 'Z',
            'age' => 99,
            'location' => 'Finland',
        )

Z was found! Their Age is: 50, They are based in: Japan
Z was found! Their Age is: 99, They are based in: Finland

Comment: In that case you have to use a loop and unset the first finding

Comment: Thanks @Sougata Bose I will give it ago!